# Syntax Error with my SQL Create Table As

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I am trying to create a new table in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio based on two existing tables.

When I execute the query below, I get an error saying that there is an:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.

SQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE AS
 SELECT OLD_TABLE.A
    , OLD_TABLE.B
    , OTHER_OLD_TABLE.C
 FROM OLD_TABLE
 INNER JOIN OTHER_OLD_TABLE
 ON OLD_TABLE.A = OTHER_OLD_TABLE.D;
```

I looked at various other problems, but could not find a solution to mine. Do you have any idea what could be wrong with the syntax?

Comment: SQL Server's syntax is `SELECT ... INTO new table FROM....`  Your example is representative of MySQL's syntax.

Comment: Thank you, I did not realise. Apologies for the duplicate post - definitely was a result of my confusion.

Comment: No need to apologize . The community is here to point you to good answers. They may already exist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use `SELECT * INTO new_table` statement just like this.

```
SELECT OLD_TABLE.A
, OLD_TABLE.B
, OTHER_OLD_TABLE.C INTO NEW_TABLE
FROM OLD_TABLE
INNER JOIN OTHER_OLD_TABLE
ON OLD_TABLE.A = OTHER_OLD_TABLE.D;
```

this statement will also create a new table as you required.